# How can I inline this function?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I have two functions, but one of the functions is only called from the other, so I would like to inline the helper function. My code looks like this:

```
data PoS =  N | V | Adj | Adv | Phr

posEntity :: Parser PoS
posEntity = 
    do pos <- string "N." <|>
              string "V." <|>
              string "Adj." <|>
              string "Adv." <|>
              string "Phr."
       return (posToPoS pos)
    <?> "part of speech"

posToPoS pos
    | pos == "N." = N
    | pos == "V." = V
    | pos == "Adj." = Adj
    | pos == "Adv." = Adv
    | pos == "Phr." = Phr
```

Clearly the posToPoS should be inlined, but I am unsure of the syntax required to do such a thing.

Thanks!

Comment: That's the compiler's job. It will decide whether it's a good idea to inline the function and if it decides against it, it's probably for the better :)

Comment: Misleading title. Most would think of the language extension INLINE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GHC probably will automatically inline it when optimizing. However, to force it to do so, simply add `{-# INLINE posToPoS #-}` somewhere in the code, preferably right next to the definition of `posToPoS`.

For making it local, so that only `posEntity` can see it, you want a where clause. Define it as such:

```
data PoS =  N | V | Adj | Adv | Phr

posEntity :: Parser PoS
posEntity = 
    do pos <- string "N." <|>
              string "V." <|>
              string "Adj." <|>
              string "Adv." <|>
              string "Phr."
       return (posToPoS pos)
    <?> "part of speech" where
        posToPoS pos
            | pos == "N." = N
            | pos == "V." = V
            | pos == "Adj." = Adj
            | pos == "Adv." = Adv
            | pos == "Phr." = Phr
```

Comment: I want it inlined for scoping reasons, not optimization. Thanks for your answer though, I did not know about that.

Comment: @Max: What do you mean, scoping reasons? You can explicitly define which functions are exported from a module and which are not.

Comment: I will need to do a different conversion depending on what I am parsing, and it would be annoying to have a bunch of different method names such as posToPoS1, posToPoS2, etc. All of these methods would be in the same module, so it would be nice to do the conversion exactly where I need the conversion done. You can see my answer below to understand what I meant.

Answer (score 8):

You can either just inline the strings in the definition to `posToPos`:

```
posToPoS "N." = N
posToPoS "V." = V
-- ... etc
```

Or, you can use the following method in your parser directly:

```
import Control.Applicative hiding (<|>)

posEntity :: Parser PoS
posEntity = 
  (string "N."   *> pure N   <|>
   string "V."   *> pure V   <|>
   string "Adj." *> pure Adj <|>
   string "Adv." *> pure Adv <|>
   string "Phr." *> pure Phr)<?> "part of speech"
```

(You might need parens around the `string "foo" *> pure Foo` parts, I forget what the operator precedence is)

Comment: or even `N <$ string "N."` etc.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, a simple case statement would seem a better solution:

```
posEntity = 
    do pos <- string "N." <|>
              string "V." <|>
              string "Adj." <|>
              string "Adv." <|>
              string "Phr."
       return $ case pos of
                  "N." -> N
                  "V." -> V
                  "Adj." -> Adj
                  "Adv." -> Adv
                  "Phr." -> Phr
    <?> "part of speech"
```

Pattern matching is generally preferrable over equality comparisons, if you have the choice.

Comment: Why the downvote? That's certainly a sensible way of "inlining" the function.

Comment: I upvoted you back to 0. I like your solution better than mine, but can you explain the use of the dollar sign? Sorry, I am extremely new to Haskell.

Comment: That's just to seperate the `return` from the `case` block.

Comment: Downvoted because the answer essentially is the same as @Max's, and the case statement adds noise to the function, while I think a `where` makes it clearer. Also, using applicative functors, there's no need to repeat the strings `"N."`, `"V."` etc. twice.

Comment: @dflemstr you've got a point there, your `Applicative` solution is arguably better. But I disagree that it's the same as just putting the auxilliary function with its guards in a `where` block, in particular I think the pattern vs. guards distinction is important.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I figured out. Sorry if I wasn't clear:

```
posEntity :: Parser PoS
posEntity = 
    do pos <- string "N." <|>
              string "V." <|>
              string "Adj." <|>
              string "Adv." <|>
              string "Phr."
       return (posToPoS pos)
    <?> "part of speech"
    where
      posToPoS pos
          | pos == "N." = N
          | pos == "V." = V
          | pos == "Adj." = Adj
          | pos == "Adv." = Adv
          | pos == "Phr." = Phr
```

Comment: Heh. It looks like you typed this up while I was editing my post with the exact same answer.